# How can I redirect from http to https?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect the user to https site with single redirection (only one 301 permanent redirection not multiple) when he visits http site.

For example when user vists http://somename.com it needs redirect https://www.somename.com

How can we do it in MVC application with the help of urlrewrite mappings?

Comment: this is usually better done at IIS level using rewrite rules, rather than within the asp.net application

Comment: @ADyson i am hosting my application in AWS environment it is different from IIS

Comment: What type of environment, exactly? If you have an ASP.NET MVC application using .NET Framework (rather than .NET Core) then underneath whatever wrapper AWS provides there **must** be an IIS server somewhere.

Comment: P.S. If you're going to ask a question which already has an obvious duplicate (in fact, probably more than one, if you search for a few seconds), then you need to explain details (such as use of AWS) which you think make it different to that, and mean that the answers in the duplicate don't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I added this to my web.config under the configuration section

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```